# Проверка IP по стране и вывод

Tags: геолокация, php, javascript

Ребят, нужен такой скрипт, написаный либо на PHP, либо на JS, который бы проверял страну посетителя сайта по IP, и если ИП пренадлежит, например, России, то выводил нужный мне HTML код, а если пренадлежит, например, Беларуси, то производился вовод другого HTML кода.

UPD

Короче, ребята, поставил скрипт JS, не работает ни с условными операторами ни без них. Если с операторами то просто пропадает меню, которое я прячу под них, а без них тупо выводятся два блока.

```
<div class="geoip" id="country-ru">
    <h1>Блок для пользователей из России</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="geoip" id="country-other">
    <h1>Блок для остальных пользователей</h1>
  </div>
```

Движок `uCoz`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Предлагаю ознакомиться с бесплатной GeoIP базой от [MaxMind](http://www.maxmind.com/app/geolitecountry) У этой базы есть [API](http://www.maxmind.com/app/api), как для PHP, так и для JavaScript. А так же есть модуль для Apache и [nginx](http://sysoev.ru/nginx/docs/http/ngx_http_geoip_module.html)

Соответственно, в случае использования PECL расширения для PHP, скрипт будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
$country = geoip_country_code_by_name($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
if ($country == 'RU') {
    header('Location: /index.ru.html', 302, true);
    exit;
}
```

Или рабочий пример на JavaScript:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Test GeoIP</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://j.maxmind.com/app/country.js"></script>
  <style type="text/css">
    .geoip { display: none; border: 1px solid #036; padding: 10px; margin: 10px; }
    p { font-size: 0.8em; text-align: center; }
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function init() {
      var id = geoip_country_code() == 'RU' ? 'country-ru' : 'country-other';
      document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body onload="init();">

  <div class="geoip" id="country-ru">
    <h1>Блок для пользователей из России</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="geoip" id="country-other">
    <h1>Блок для остальных пользователей</h1>
  </div>

  <p>Лицензия использования JavaScript API требует наличия обратной ссылки на <a href="http://www.maxmind.com/">MaxMind</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Однако, с точки зрения производительности, лучше использовать модуль для Apache или nginx.

Comment: о, за код спасибо. Просто я сам в PHP нубик, сйчас попробую сделать, но думаю нужно будет сделать, чтобы выводило не на страницу, а просто HTML код.
И можно с вами как нибудь переговорить лично?

Comment: Сейчас попробывал, но не получилось, т.к в PHP вообще дуб дубом...Илья или еще кто нибудь помощете в составлении скрипта?

Comment: Нужно предварительно установить соответствующее [PECL расширение][1]. Либо воспользуйтесь API для JavaScript.

> И можно с вами как нибудь переговорить лично?

Если с целью консультаций по PHP, то не стоит =)

  [1]: http://www.php.net/manual/en/geoip.installation.php

Comment: Js как раз кстати) Правда и там я нубик) Большое спасибо за инфу. Скажите, вот так будет работать?

    <body onload="init();">
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
    if (country-ru) {
        Блок для пользователей из России
    }
    else {
        тут еще что-нибудь
    }
     </script>
    </body>

Или какое условие прописывать?

Comment: if (geoip_country_code() == 'RU') {
}

[JavaScript Introduction][http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_intro.asp]