# Определение местонахождения пользователя по IP

Tags: геолокация, php

Программа определяет IP пользователя и по этому IP определяет месторасположение пользователя (регион, город). Скажите, пожалуйста, как это можно реализовать на PHP?

Answer (score 2):

Недавно уже был аналогичный [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/15771/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0-ip-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4)

Answer (score 0):

Здесь статья по этому поводу: [определение местоположения пользователя по его IP](http://js-php.ru/web-development/php-development/get-geo-info-by-ip/).

Comment: Нет не то.

Comment: Как это не то? Что вас не устраивает?

Comment: GeoIP

Comment: Без закачек различных левых баз и тд.

Comment: http://www.softtime.ru/scripts/whois.php разбирайтесь